# Vuejs Es6 class reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class, vue-reactivity

i'm trying to have a computed property in vuejs associated to a es6 class.
My Vue instance looks like this:

```
...
props: ['customClass'],
computed: {
    localClass: {
         get() {
             return this.customClass
         },
         set (value) {
             console.log("changed")
         }
     }
 }
 ...
```

My class looks like this

```
class CustomClass {
    constructor () {
        this.selected = false
    }
}
```

If i try to do something like that:

```
this.localClass.selected = true
```

but the setter is never called, like the reactivity has been lost and i don't understand why.

I also try:

```
Vue.set(this.localClass, 'selected', true)
```

I pass customClass as a prop, but even creating a new instance directly in the component it doesn't change the result.

In vuejs docs i don't recall a section talking about reactivity problem in es6 class, so i was wondering if someone know why and how to make my class reactive.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not setting `localClass`, which would activate the setter, you are setting a member of `localClass`, which does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setter of a computed property, say `myComputedProperty`, is triggered when you assign to that property (e.g. `this.myComputedProperty = {something: 'else'}`.

What you probably are looking for is a [**watcher**, more specifically, a watcher with `deep: true`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch), such as:

```
watch: {
  localClass: {
    deep: true,
    handler() {
      out.innerHTML += "watched!";
    }
  }
},
```

Demo below.

```js
class CustomClass {
  constructor() {
    this.selected = false
  }
}
Vue.component('custom', {
  template: '#custom',
  props: ['customClass'],
  computed: {
    localClass: {
      get() {
        return this.customClass
      },
      set(value) {
        out.innerHTML += "changed!\n";
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    localClass: {
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        out.innerHTML += "watched!\n";
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    assignToSelected() {
      this.localClass.selected = true
    },
    assignToLocalClass() {
      this.localClass = {
        selected: true
      }
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: new CustomClass()
  },
})
```

```css
#out { background: black; color: gray; }
span { font-size: x-small; font-family: verdana }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<template id="custom">
  <div>
    {{ localClass }}
    <br>
    <button @click="assignToSelected">assignToSelected</button>
    <span>Note: will trigger "watched!" just once, because, since the value is hardcoded in the method (see code) subsequent clicks won't modify the value.</span>
    <br><br>
    <button @click="assignToLocalClass">assignToLocalClass</button>
    <span>Note: assignToLocalClass() will trigger the computed setter, but wont trigger the watcher because the computed setter currently sets nothing, so nothing changed for the watcher to trigger.</span>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <custom :custom-class="test"></custom>
</div>

<pre id="out"></pre>
```